# Subscript out of range - error # 9

Tags: excel, vba

While running the below mentioned code, I received `Subscript out of range - error 9`. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
Sub testing1()
    Dim Fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim Fldr As Folder
    Dim Fpath As String
    Dim Fl As File
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Myvalue As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Myvalue = Application.InputBox("Enter your value")

    Set Fso = New FileSystemObject
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        Fpath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    Set Fldr = Fso.GetFolder(Fpath)

    For Each Fl In Fldr.Files
        For Each Fl In Fldr.Files
            For Each Sh In Workbooks(Fl.Name).Sheets
                For Each cell In Sh.UsedRange
                    If cell.Value = Myvalue Then
                        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 12
                    End If
                Next cell
            Next Sh
        Next Fl
    Next Fl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make changes to the data inside closed workbooks. You have to open them first. In your loop, you should try opening the workbook first, then applying the formatting, then closing it. See the following code:

```
Sub testing1()

    Dim TargetBook As Workbook
    Dim Fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim Fldr As Folder
    Dim Fpath As String
    Dim Fl As File
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Myvalue As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Myvalue = Application.InputBox("Enter your value")

    Set Fso = New FileSystemObject
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        Fpath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    Set Fldr = Fso.GetFolder(Fpath)

    For Each Fl In Fldr.Files
        Set TargetBook = Workbooks.Open(Fl.Name) '--Added this.
        For Each Sh In TargetBook.Worksheets '--Changed this.
            For Each cell In Sh.UsedRange
                If cell.Value = Myvalue Then
                    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 12
                End If
            Next cell
        Next Sh
        TargetBook.Close '--Added this.
    Next Fl

End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: + 1 One tip though, Instead of looping, you could use `.Replace`?